# How to test the values of CSS styles set for a DIV that depends on a hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs

I am working on a project and need to come up with a custom solution to check whether the page is being accessed from a mobile, tablet, or desktop device as well as the orientation used by the device - in the scenario of mobile and tablet because I tried to use the `react-device-detect` library but for some reason was not working for me properly.

Here is the code for my "custom" hook:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";

const useDeviceType = () => {
    const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(false)
    const [isTablet, setIsTablet] = useState(false)
    const [isPortrait, setIsPortrait] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleResize = () => {
            setIsMobile(window.innerHeight <= 1024)

            if (window.screen.orientation.type === 'portrait-primary') {
                setIsTablet(window.innerWidth > 627 && window.innerWidth <= 1024)
                setIsPortrait(true)
            } else {
                setIsTablet(window.innerHeight > 627 && window.innerHeight <= 1024)
                setIsPortrait(false)
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)

        handleResize()

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
        }
    }, [isMobile, isTablet, isPortrait]);

    return {isMobile, isTablet, isPortrait}
}

export default useDeviceType
```

being this a hook I am using from my component as follows:

```
function App() {
    const {isMobile, isTablet, isPortrait} = useDeviceType()

    let rightColumnCssStyle
    let leftColumnCssStyle

    if (isMobile) {
        rightColumnCssStyle = `${styles.defaultRightColumn} ${styles.forMobileRightColumn}`
        leftColumnCssStyle = `${styles.defaultLeftColumn} ${styles.forMobileLeftColumn}`
    } else if (isTablet) {
        rightColumnCssStyle = `${styles.defaultRightColumn} ${styles.forTabletRight}`
        leftColumnCssStyle = `${styles.defaultLeftColumn} ${styles.forTabletLeft}`
        
        if (isPortrait) {
            rightColumnCssStyle = `${styles.defaultRightColumn} ${styles.forTabletRight} ${styles.withPortraitMode}`
            leftColumnCssStyle = `${styles.defaultLeftColumn} ${styles.forTabletLeft} ${styles.withPortraitMode}`
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className={rightColumnCssStyle}>Some Content</div>
            <div className={leftColumnCssStyle}>Some Content</div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I was able to mock the `window` orientation property successfully in a test but I wonder if I can go beyond that and test whether the value of `isMobile` and `isTablet`.

This is how I am mocking the value of the orientation property:

```
const mockScreenOrientation = jest.fn()

Object.defineProperty(window.screen, 'orientation', {
    value: {
        get type() {
            return mockScreenOrientation()
        }
    }
)
```

I also know that I can use something like:

```
global.innerWidth = 500;
global.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'))
```

But how can I check the CSS applied to each DIV on the resulting render that depends on `isMobile`, `isTablet`, and `isPortrait` as shown in the above code snippet on a test?

I want to test the `App` component, with a mocked `useDeviceType` hook result, and assertion on the two div elements having the expected class names.

I tried to use `testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library` but it is giving me a lot of headaches with dependencies in the project (the project is using an old React version as well as NextJS - at this moment - is a nightmare to migrate those, and still is a future goal) so I give up.

> Note: the above solution is not perfect and is not intended to be a library or something like that but I am open to improvements because I am human and can make mistakes.

Comment: Why even use an if statement at all? `setIsPortait(window.screen.orientation.type === 'portrait-primary')`

Comment: What do you mean by how to check the value of `isMobile` and `isTablet`?

Comment: React-Testing-Library (*and React-Hooks-Testing-Library by re-export*) is the standard way to test React components and hooks, for the most part. What specific help do you need in testing? Please [edit] to clarify the problem and include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with.

Comment: @LinDu I have edited the question to clarify a little bit what I am trying to achieve, hopefully, reads better and is more understandable than before

Comment: @DrewReese same, I have made an edit and hopefully is what you were asking for as for the reproducible example is hard for me to get a real example or something to reproduce the very same issues I am having on this project, let me know if the edit is enough

Comment: You still haven't shown us what you are trying to unit test. I'm guessing you want to test the `App` component, with a mocked `useDeviceType` hook result, and assertion on the two `div` elements having the expected classnames.

Comment: @DrewReese sorry for all the confusion, your guess is correct, that is exactly what I am trying to test